# Xing out values in excel

Tags: excel

I have a very large excel file with values that have 4 after the decimal, so for example ".0123".

Is there a way that I can replace this with XXXX? Basically, I'm Xing out all the values but doing it cell by cell is too time consuming.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This would convert your cells from numbers to text. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Also, is it always 4 X's? Are these rounded? Would .012345 be replaced with 4 or 6 X's?

Comment: Try using the following custom cell format: `0.XXXX` at least that way you won't convert your numbers to string

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, this is an interesting enough trick that you should post as answer!

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not as clear as I could have been. I would like to replace the numbers with 4 Xs. The number is actually "0.0123" - so in total 6 digits. So from 6 numeric numbers to 4 Xs. If it's 6 Xs, that would be fine too because then I could use run the replace all function in excel.

Answer (score 1):

Select all the cells. Right click > Format. Choose Custom number format and edit an existing format to read "0.XXXX"

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, didn't even know you can do this.